# MySQL: Moving Aggregate / Running Total

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

I have the following schema and the qrys for getting a running total. With this as a starting point, how can I obtain a moving three days' running total, if the row name is 2012-09-02, then the running total should be the total of 2012-09-01 + 2012-09-02 + 2012-09-03? The ideal results are as follow

**[Ideal Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff56/11/1)**:

```
| ORDER_DATE | QUANTITY | RUNNINGTOTAL |
|------------|----------|--------------|
| 2012-09-01 |       11 |           36 | -> 11 + 25
| 2012-09-02 |       25 |           86 | -> 11 + 25 + 50
| 2012-09-03 |       50 |          125 | -> 25 + 50 + 50
| 2012-09-04 |       50 |          101 | -> 50 + 50 + 1
| 2012-09-05 |        1 |          --  |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff56/11)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`order_id` int, `order_date` varchar(10), `cust_id` int, `order_line` int, `book_id` int, `quantity` int, `order_price` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`order_id`, `order_date`, `cust_id`, `order_line`, `book_id`, `quantity`, `order_price`)
VALUES
    (1002, '2012-09-08', 234138, 1, 1107, 11, 25.00),
    (1002, '2012-09-08', 234138, 2, 1106, 12, 25.50),
    (1003, '2012-09-08', 200368, 1, 1104, 5, 45.00),
    (1004, '2012-09-18', 221297, 1, 1106, 2, 18.25),
    (1005, '2012-09-28', 290298, 1, 1142, 2, 42.45),
    (1005, '2012-09-28', 290298, 2, 1107, 4, 21.50),
    (1006, '2012-09-28', 208950, 1, 1103, 10, 10.95),
    (1007, '2012-09-03', 276381, 1, 1448, 50, 25.00),
    (1008, '2012-09-10', 276381, 1, 1670, 50, 40.00),
    (1010, '2012-09-10', 218709, 1, 1537, 50, 25.00),
    (1011, '2012-09-10', 261502, 1, 1103, 2, 10.95),
    (1012, '2012-09-05', 260368, 1, 1128, 1, 49.95),
    (1027, '2012-09-18', 234709, 1, 2001, 21, 49.99),
    (1027, '2012-09-18', 234709, 2, 1077, 22, 10.99),
    (1028, '2012-09-20', 234709, 1, 2001, 1, 19.78),
    (1028, '2012-09-20', 234709, 2, 2002, 22, 40.00),
    (1028, '2012-09-20', 234709, 3, 2004, 1, 49.95),
    (1028, '2012-09-20', 234709, 4, 2006, 1, 46.95),
    (1030, '2012-09-22', 234709, 1, 1279, 1, 40.49),
    (1035, '2012-09-22', 221297, 1, 1689, 1, 55.19),
    (1039, '2012-09-22', 212921, 1, 1448, 1, 30.00),
    (1039, '2012-09-22', 212921, 2, 1162, 2, 34.95),
    (1040, '2012-09-28', 263119, 1, 2025, 560, 39.00),
    (1040, '2012-09-28', 263119, 2, 2018, 2, 49.99),
    (1602, '2012-09-14', 217796, 1, 1103, 2, 10.95),
    (1602, '2012-09-14', 217796, 2, 1106, 1, 29.00),
    (1603, '2012-09-10', 261502, 1, 2009, 5, 34.95),
    (1603, '2012-09-10', 261502, 3, 2007, 1, 39.00),
    (1603, '2012-09-10', 261502, 4, 2001, 1, 39.00),
    (1604, '2012-09-10', 217796, 1, 1103, 25, 10.95),
    (1604, '2012-09-10', 217796, 2, 1106, 15, 29.00),
    (1606, '2012-09-14', 217796, 1, 1106, 5, 34.95),
    (1606, '2012-09-14', 217796, 2, 1107, 5, 20.95),
    (1606, '2012-09-14', 217796, 3, 2001, 5, 39.00),
    (1610, '2012-09-15', 263119, 1, 1103, 2, 12.00),
    (1615, '2012-09-15', 261502, 1, 1103, 2, 12.00),
    (22803, '2012-09-02', 224038, 1, 1128, 25, 45.00),
    (22803, '2012-09-02', 224038, 2, 1301, 15, 45.50),
    (22803, '2012-09-02', 224038, 3, 1304, 5, 59.99),
    (22804, '2012-09-04', 239427, 1, 1304, 50, 45.00),
    (22804, '2012-09-04', 239427, 2, 1305, 50, 9.99),
    (22805, '2012-09-06', 224038, 1, 1104, 5, 45.00),
    (22805, '2012-09-06', 224038, 2, 1306, 5, 250.12),
    (22806, '2012-09-23', 239427, 1, 1107, 1, 25.00),
    (22807, '2012-09-23', 224038, 1, 1175, 1, 34.99),
    (22808, '2012-09-24', 290298, 1, 1182, 1, 45.00),
    (22809, '2012-09-25', 239427, 1, 1104, 5, 45.00),
    (22810, '2012-09-25', 218709, 1, 1678, 5, 49.99),
    (22810, '2012-09-25', 218709, 2, 1162, 5, 35.00),
    (22811, '2012-09-30', 261502, 1, 1478, 5, 45.00),
    (22812, '2012-09-30', 239427, 1, 1357, 50, 26.00),
    (22812, '2012-09-30', 239427, 2, 1425, 50, 28.09),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 1, 1175, 1, 45.00),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 2, 1180, 1, 49.99),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 3, 1182, 1, 45.00),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 4, 1184, 1, 49.99),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 5, 1185, 1, 49.99),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 6, 1188, 1, 49.99),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 7, 1877, 1, 45.00),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 8, 1175, 1, 34.90),
    (22813, '2012-09-30', 239427, 9, 1425, 1, 25.90),
    (31884, '2012-09-22', 290298, 1, 1278, 1, 48.00),
    (31884, '2012-09-22', 290298, 2, 1199, 9, 17.99),
    (31885, '2012-09-22', 217796, 1, 1448, 50, 25.00),
    (31889, '2012-09-22', 227105, 1, 1109, 18, 50.60),
    (32800, '2012-09-29', 217796, 1, 1128, 50, 25.00),
    (32890, '2012-09-01', 212921, 1, 1103, 11, 15.00),
    (32891, '2012-09-05', 212921, 1, 1142, 5, 15.00),
    (32892, '2012-09-10', 272611, 1, 2002, 5, 15.00),
    (32893, '2012-09-15', 200368, 1, 1689, 1, 55.19),
    (32894, '2012-09-18', 234138, 1, 1894, 1, 35.99),
    (32895, '2012-09-18', 218709, 1, 1689, 1, 55.19),
    (32896, '2012-09-18', 218709, 1, 1894, 1, 35.99),
    (32897, '2012-09-22', 261502, 1, 1110, 2, 50.00),
    (32898, '2012-09-22', 261502, 1, 2006, 3, 20.00),
    (32899, '2012-09-29', 261502, 1, 1128, 50, 25.00)
;

CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`OrderDate` varchar(10), `3 Day Order Count` int, `3 Day Total Quantity` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`OrderDate`, `3 Day Order Count`, `3 Day Total Quantity`)
VALUES
    ('2012-09-01', 99, 999),
    ('2012-09-02', 99, 999),
    ('2012-09-03', 99, 999),
    ('2012-09-05', 99, 999),
    ('2012-09-06', 99, 999),
    ('2012-09-07', 99, 999)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
set @runningorder := 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff56/11/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
set @runningqty := 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff56/11/1)**:

**Query 3**:

```
select order_date
, @runningorder := @runningorder + TotalOrder as TotalOrder
, @runningqty := @runningqty + TotalQty as TotayQuantity
from (
select order_date
, count(order_id) as TotalOrder
, sum(quantity) as TotalQty
from table1
group by order_date) t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff56/11/2)**:

```
| ORDER_DATE | TOTALORDER | TOTAYQUANTITY |
|------------|------------|---------------|
| 2012-09-01 |          1 |            11 |
| 2012-09-02 |          4 |            56 |
| 2012-09-03 |          5 |           106 |
| 2012-09-04 |          7 |           206 |
| 2012-09-05 |          9 |           212 |
| 2012-09-06 |         11 |           222 |
| 2012-09-08 |         14 |           250 |
| 2012-09-10 |         23 |           404 |
| 2012-09-14 |         28 |           422 |
| 2012-09-15 |         31 |           427 |
| 2012-09-18 |         37 |           475 |
| 2012-09-20 |         41 |           500 |
| 2012-09-22 |         51 |           588 |
| 2012-09-23 |         53 |           590 |
| 2012-09-24 |         54 |           591 |
| 2012-09-25 |         57 |           606 |
| 2012-09-28 |         62 |          1184 |
| 2012-09-29 |         64 |          1284 |
| 2012-09-30 |         76 |          1398 |
```

Comment: How should the 3-day total be calculated when dates have gaps (e.g. from your sample data `2013-09-06`, `2013-09-08`, `2013-09-10`)?

Comment: I was able to do the three days total by treating the missing days with zero values, but have no idea how to do this if we were to skip the missing days. So `9/5/2012 + 9/6/2012 + 9/7/2012 where 9/7/2012 is treated as zero value` is doable. But `9/5/2012 + 9/6/2012 + 9/8/2012` no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**EDITED**

```
SELECT a.order_date, a.quantity, (ifnull(a.quantity, 0) +
ifnull((SELECT b.quantity FROM table1 b
        WHERE a.order_date > b.order_date
        ORDER BY order_date DESC, quantity desc LIMIT 1), 0) +
ifnull((SELECT c.quantity FROM table1 c
        WHERE a.order_date < c.order_date
        ORDER BY order_date ASC, quantity desc LIMIT 1), 0)) AS totalquantity
FROM table1 a group by a.order_date ORDER BY 1;
```

**[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff56/53/0)**